# I cannot get Epoch Charts to display output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, epoch.js

I'm trying to create a dashboard that shows some fairly simple data. I thought the simplest way would be to use a web page and a charting tool, Epoch Charts seemed to be a good choice.

I have installed all the relevant dependencies and followed the instructions.

When I create the HTML page, I don't get any error, but I get no chart (just a blank page). I'm running a local host on Apache.

I've tried a lot of different ways of doing this, I just can't figure out why I get nothing at all. I used npm to install jQuery, D3, epoch, etc. in the relevant site directory.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/epoch.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/epoch.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="area" class="epoch category10" style="height: 200px;"></div>
  <script>
    var data = [{
        label: 'Layer 1',
        values: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        }, {
          x: 1,
          y: 1
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        }]
      },
      {
        label: 'Layer 2',
        values: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        }, {
          x: 1,
          y: 1
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 4
        }]
      }
    ];

    var areaChartInstance = $('#area').epoch({
      type: 'area',
      data: data,
      axes: ['left', 'right', 'bottom']
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Epoch Changelog](https://github.com/epochjs/epoch/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), the current version (0.8.4) has been released on October 30th, 2015. Therefore, the issue must be related to incorrect versions of libraries it depends on.

`Epoch` [package.json](https://github.com/epochjs/epoch/blob/master/package.json) states that the library depends on `d3 v3.4.13`. If you really want to use `Epoch`, make sure, you're using `d3 v3`, same as I did with your code below.

```js
var data = [
  {
    label: 'Layer 1',
    values: [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }]
  },
  {
    label: 'Layer 2',
    values: [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 4 }]
  }
];

var areaChartInstance = $('#area').epoch({
  type: 'area',
  data: data,
  axes: ['left', 'right', 'bottom']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/epoch/0.8.4/js/epoch.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/epoch/0.8.4/css/epoch.css">
<div id="area" class="epoch" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```